# uninitialized constant Omrails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

When I execute `rails s` the server won't open and I receive the following error:

```
Users/thomaspouliquen/whereisthepolice/config/routes.rb:2:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Omrails (NameError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:108:in `reload_routes!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/devise-3.2.1/lib/devise/rails.rb:14:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `execute_hook'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:52:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/thomaspouliquen/whereisthepolice/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/thomaspouliquen/whereisthepolice/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /Users/thomaspouliquen/whereisthepolice/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/thomaspouliquen/whereisthepolice/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

What is the issue?

Comment: Do you have the same versions of Ruby, RoR and any other gems as specified in the tutorial? If you don't, this is the most likely cause. Comment with the tutorial link and I'll try to help you out.

Comment: The error message is "uninitialized constant Omrails". What is `Omrails`? Where have you defined it?

Comment: Was just about to post that, make sure that you haven't missed any 'require' statements or such (in regards to Omrails)

Comment: where do i see the 'require' statements ? im starting to get crazy about this i believe i havent changed anything

Comment: Can you do a `git grep Omrails` and let us know the output? (I'm assuming you're using git and have been committing all your changes) Is `Omrails` something you created deliberately or no? Is it possible that, say, your cat stepped on your keyboard and typed `Om` in front of `rails` in some file and that got saved?

Comment: when i do git grp omrails this shows up

Comment: config/application.rb:module Omrails
config/routes.rb:Omrails::Application.routes.draw do
macbook-de-thomas-pouliquen:whereisthepolice thomaspouliquen$

Comment: unfortunately i dont have any cat :/

Comment: macbook-de-thomas-pouliquen:whereisthepolice thomaspouliquen$ git grep whereisthepolice
README.md:#whereisthepolice
app/views/layouts/_footer.html.erb:             <%= link_to "Whereisthepolice", "http://www.whereisthepolice.com" %>
config/initializers/session_store.rb:Whereisthepolice::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_whereisthepolice_session
whereisthepolice.pub:ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC4EK+JmKgRVvD++1qrQTmbXXE5hXncu7f77Ba7wUroyEjye9DuckBtYEe8KbI9r16r8pci6zPWe
(END)

Answer (score 0):

Did you by any chance change the name of your application?

Perhaps it was named `WhereIsThePolice` and now it's `Omrails`?

If you want to change the name of your app, you have to make changes to several files, so let me know if this is the case.

Comment: i actually dont know how i would have done that. i'm very new to rails and it was working perfectly until two hours ago.

Comment: how do you change the name of the app ? to check if I did not do it by mistake

Comment: Well, first, what's on line 2 in `routes.rb`? And what's on the first few lines of `config/application.rb`, specifically the `module ...` line?

Comment: Omrails::Application.routes.draw do           
Whereisthepolice::Application.routes.draw do      this is the two first lines of my routes.rb

Comment: That's odd, why are there `Omrails::Application` and `Whereisthepolice::Application` lines? There should be only one, matching what's on the `config/application.rb` file.